# Converting audio blob to file for upload to backend (without saving it locally)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, blob, strapi

EDIT: there were a couple of small typos/errors in here, which are corrected now and they solved half of the issues. The other half is in the accepted answer.

...

I am recording microphone-audio on the client side (nuxt/vue) and want to send it to my backend (Strapi). I have a MediaRecorder recorder and when the recording stops the data is being added to my recordingFile array. This part works, after recording I can play it back with the embedded player.

HTML part:

```
<audio
  id="localaudio"
  ..
></audio>
```

JS:

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream);

...     

recorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", function(e) { 
        document.querySelector("#localaudio").src = URL.createObjectURL(e.data); //add it to the player element on the page for playback
        recordingFile.push(e.data); // pushing to array recordingFile
      });
```

However, I am having troubles uploading it to my Strapi backend. I think the reason is I'm trying to upload a blob when Strapi expects a file.

```
  let blob = new Blob(recordingFile, { type: "audio/ogg" });

  const data = {
    "user" : "test",
    "files.File" : blob //prefix is strapi convention
  };

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('data', JSON.stringify(data));

  axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "http://localhost:1337/recordings",
    data: formData,
    headers: {
      "content-type": `multipart/form-data;`
    }
  })
```

I do get a positive response and a new entry with user="test", but the file field stays empty. I tried sending the file-URL (URL.createObjectURL(..)) instead of the blob itself but it doesn't work either.

I am following instructions from [strapi documentation](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/plugins/upload.html#upload-file-during-entry-creation) but it uses files from the filesystem, not blobs created in the browser.

Any hints?

EDIT:
recording.settings.json:

```
{
  "kind": "collectionType",
  "collectionName": "recordings",
  "info": {
    "name": "Recording"
  },
  "options": {
    "increments": true,
    "timestamps": true,
    "draftAndPublish": true
  },
  "attributes": {
    "File": {
      "model": "file",
      "via": "related",
      "allowedTypes": [
        "images",
        "files",
        "videos"
      ],
      "plugin": "upload",
      "required": false
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the JSON of the model as well?

Comment: Added it above..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation actually suggests that you append the file or blob (both should work) to the `FormData` instance instead of to the `data` object.

```
let blob = new Blob(recordingFile, { type: "audio/ogg" });
let file = new File([blob], 'recording.ogg');

const data = {
  "user" : "test",
};

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('files.file', file);
formData.append('data', JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: Thanks! 
This does in fact upload a file into the upload directory. There are still two things wrong though: 1) the file is corrupt and 2) the "file" field in the recordings collection stays empty (that was why I didn't realise the code is actually uploading the file)

Comment: Not sure if it really helps, but you could turn your `Blob` into a `File` and then send it, although `File` is just a `Blob` with two extra properties [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File). Otherwise, maybe check if the `.ogg` blob can be played to check if the recording is working correctly.

Comment: The corrupted file came from here:  new Blob([recordingFile], ..) instead of new Blob(recordingFile, ..) 
I changed the recordingFile from a single var to an array and forgot to change the call of the Blob constructor accordingly.

So I can upload a working file into the directory, but it doesn't get connected to the field in the collection yet. Maybe I have to do it in 2 steps, but according to the Strapi docs it should work in one go..

Comment: It was a typo/case error:

it has to be "formData.append('files.File', blob, 'recording.ogg')" instead of files.file

Comment: Nice! Why the capitalization if I may ask? Is that a pattern in Straps?

Comment: I don't recall doing it, tbh. Capitalization was probably a typo during setup on my part or maybe the term "file" gets treated differently than others, I don't know.. thanks for your help though

Answer (score 0):

Apparently when sending `formData` one is not supposed to include a `content-type` in request headers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is because the browser automatically adds a `boundary` definition to the `content-type` header when sending FormData. If you set the header manually you override this, as explained in [this article](https://muffinman.io/blog/uploading-files-using-fetch-multipart-form-data/).